# How to share the parent class variables to third class through the child class in python?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
    class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = self.method1()
        self.variable2 = self.method2()
        self.variable3 = self.method3()
        self.variable4 = self.method4()
        #.........(for example I have 100 variables here)

    def method1(self):
        return 100

    def method2(self):
        return 200

    def method3(self):
        return 300

    def method4(self):
        return 400


class Third():
    def __init__(self):
        a = 1

    def call(self):
        value = self.variable3 + 1
        return value


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.getanswer = self.method11()

    def method11(self):
        value_count = Third().call()
        return value_count
obj = Child()
```

It throwed the following Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Third' object has no attribute 'variable3'
```

Here I wanted to send all the values of parent to `Third` Class through `Child` class. How can I achieve it? I know that I can pass `Parent` class variables seperately in  directly as a parameter in the class `Third` as following:

```
value_count = Third(self.variable3).call()
```

and change the `Third` Class constructor accordingly. But I don't want to do it as my `Parent` class has some time taking operations to do.

Also I don't want to make class `Third` as child to the class `Parent`.

So How can I recognize the `Parent` class variables(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, ....) in `Third` Class through `Child` Class ?

Comment: Why don't you pass the Parent or Child instances to Third call() method?

Comment: I had some time-consuming opeartions in parent class which are common to both the child class and Third class(which are defined in constructor of Parent). So When I instantiate the child class,  the constructor of Parent will get executed only once and I wanted to use those variables in the third Class. And I wanted to provide the scope of all those 100 variables(assume) to Third class in an easy way rather than sending each and every variable to Third class.

Comment: You can pass the parent/child instance to the Third constructor and update() the Third \_\_dict\_\_ with this instance \_\_dict\_\_.  It will work but I think it is anti-pattern.
If you don't want to inherit, you should access the parent instance variables as third_instance.parent.var_x